# Android service onStartCommand never called

Tags: android, android-service

I noticed that `Service.START_STICKY` doesn't work and when I tokk a closer look, I saw the onCreate() is running but onStartCommand is not called.

Any ideas why?

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {

    mGlobalData = GlobalData.getInstance();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (mTimer == null)
        mTimer = new Timer();

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate()");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int t = START_STICKY;
    Log.e(TAG, "call me redundant BABY!  onStartCommand service");

    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you have the same situation I had, my `Service` starts up and runs just fine (`onCreate()` and `onServiceConnected()` are both invoked) but `onStartCommand(Intent,int)` was never called.  I found it's because the system started my `Service` instead of me explicitly starting the `Service` in code. According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)):

> [`onStartCommand(Intent,int)` is] called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service by calling `startService(Intent)`

So I had to call `startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class))` explicitly in code to get `onStartCommand(Intent,int)` to trigger.  Note that doing this will not restart the Service created by the system and it won't create a new instance of that Service either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to insert the line `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` at the end of `onCreate()`. The debugger didn't reach `onStartCommand()`'s breakpoints for me until I did this.

Comment: Worked for me. But when I removed it from the onCreate method to confirm that this was infact the problem, the problem had disappeared.